# Propel : use format on demand with Twig

Tags: php, twig, propel

Using Propel ORM, I need to parse a very large set of database results to display it and to export it to CSV.

Today, I get fatal errors like `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted` from my peer object (the size to parse can be up to 800 000 items).

So I tried to use the format on demand, which hydrates on the fly (supposed not to consume memory) with :

```
->setFormatter(ModelCriteria::FORMAT_ON_DEMAND)
```

It works well in PHP only mode, but using Twig nothing is displayed (with no error in the log)

I think that, with format on demand, the resulting object cannot be used by Twig (for example, `count($result_list)` returns -1 which is not possible normally)... Probably the implementation of the twig "for" is different from the "foreach" that should be used .

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to set it up so the CSV can be downloaded?

Comment: It is working to generate a CSV (it is pure PHP and I can use a foreach loop that seems compatible with the Propel object), but not with Twig, so I cannot display it in HTML. This is due to the 'formater on demand' but how to make it work ?

Comment: Hi @Rolintocour.  It seems that Twig has some memory issues when handling your results object, try and see if you can flatten it into a pure php array (not PropelArrayObject).  It may still be Iterator object with some extra stuff in it that you may not need.  
 Just out of curiousity, how big is the your results set in terms of column and row count?

Comment: There may be up to 50 000 results (displayed with slickgrind). I will try with a PHP array but I think I will loose the 'format on demand' option

Comment: You can try and do ->toArray() within the loop, so it's flattened just before you pass it to twig